# I cannot add a jpanel to a jframe

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have the following code, but my JPanel just doesn't show. I can't figure out why. Do you see why? All I see is the JFrame with black background

```
public class ShapeFrame extends JFrame 
{
    private JPanel outlinePanel;

    public ShapeFrame(LinkedList<Coordinate> list)
    {
        super("Outline / Abstract Image");
        setSize(950, 500);
        setLayout(null);
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel outlinePanel = new JPanel();
        outlinePanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        outlinePanel.setBorder(null);
        outlinePanel.setBounds(50, 50, 400, 400);
        add(outlinePanel);


//      abstractPanel = new JPanel();
//      abstractPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
//      abstractPanel.setBounds(500, 50, 400, 400);
//      add(abstractPanel);
    }
```

Comment: I agree with @MadProgrammer, that you should avoid null layouts, but your current code doesn't show the error. If you display this JFrame the JPanel will be added and will be seen. The only other error I see is that your outlinePanel variable local to the ShapeFrame constructor shadows the otulinePanel class field which of course remains null. Perhaps that's the source of your error and confusion.

Comment: When I run the code that you posted here, I get a window with a gray background and a white square inside (which I assume is your `outlinePanel`. Please post an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) which recreates the exact problem that you are asking about.

Comment: 1) What does `outlinePanel` do in the final product?  The `LinkedList<Coordinate>` suggests it might be rendering the list of co-ords.  2) There is no need to extend frame, just use an instance of one.  There is probably also no need to extend panel, but I cannot be sure until I understand what it does and how it is to be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All I get is a frame with a white square in it...

You should use `getContentPane().setBackground()` to set the back ground of the frame

Frames are made up of layers.  Typically, the content that you see is added (automatically in most cases) to the content pane, which covers the frame.

[image]

*(Picture borrowed from the Java Trails)*

So setting the background of the frame "appears" to have no effect.

Using your code...

[image]

Using `getContent().setBackground(...)`

[image]

This is the code I used to test your code with...

```
public class BadLayout01 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new BadLayout01();
    }

    public BadLayout01() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                ShapeFrame shapeFrame = new ShapeFrame();
                shapeFrame.setSize(525, 525);
                shapeFrame.setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    }

    public class ShapeFrame extends JFrame {

        private JPanel outlinePanel;

        public ShapeFrame() {
            super("Outline / Abstract Image");
            setSize(950, 500);
            setLayout(null);
            getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
//            setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            JPanel outlinePanel = new JPanel();
            outlinePanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            outlinePanel.setBorder(null);
            outlinePanel.setBounds(50, 50, 400, 400);
            add(outlinePanel);


//      abstractPanel = new JPanel();
//      abstractPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
//      abstractPanel.setBounds(500, 50, 400, 400);
//      add(abstractPanel);
        }
    }
}
```